# Nodemailer Error with Namecheap: read ECONRESET

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, namecheap

I'm getting the following error using nodemailer using namecheap as a host. It's occurring randomly but it happens very often. Do you guys have any idea what this could be?

```
Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27) {
 errno: 'ECONNRESET',
 code: 'ESOCKET',
 syscall: 'read',
 command: 'CONN'
}
```

This is my transporter and I define it in the global scope:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
   host: "mail.privateemail.com",
   port: 587,
   secure: false,
   auth:{
      user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS
   },
   tls:{
      secureProtocol: "TLSv1_method"
   }
});
```

Then I send it according the documentation:

```
const mailOptions = {
    from: *FROM_EMAIL*
    to: *TO_EMAIL*,
    subject: *SOME_TEXT*
    html: *SOME_HTML*
};

await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem recently and I solved it by adding the ciphers, rejectunauthorized to the tls, and switching the port to 465 and secure to true.

Additionally, my biggest problem was that in the from field in your mail object, it has to be an email address and not just a name.

from: "Jerry" --- would not work.
from: "Jerry@hotmail.com" --- worked fine.

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
   host: "mail.privateemail.com",
   port: 465,
   secure: true, // Must be true, false will fail
   auth:{
      user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS
   },
   tls:{
      rejectUnauthorized: false,  
      ciphers: "SSLv3"  
   }
});
```

One more thing, make sure that your code looks like this if you're using a switch method

```
export default async (req, res) => {
    switch (req.method) {
        case "POST":

        var transport = {
                tls: {
        ...

        var transporter = nodemailer.create......
        transporter.verify........

        // Then your mail below
        break
```

When I had transport, transporter and transporter.verify outside of the switch function I was getting all sorts of bugs and sometimes the emails wouldn't send. Inside the switch function they work.

Comment: The only option needed for me was the `host` and `auth` options; the others weren't needed to make it work.